# Starting Tomcat 6 with only Manager App running

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6, manager-app

Is it possible to start Tomcat with only the Manager webapp running?

I have multiple webapps in the appBase and don't want them to startup automatically at startup.

If I set autoDeploy="false" deployOnStartup="false", I don't have access to the manager webapp on startup, because it is in the same appBase.

I guess an alternate solution would be to start the manager app somehow after startup, but I'm not aware of how that is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could [use the TCD to generate an ant build file](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/deployer-howto.html#Deploying%20using%20the%20Client%20Deployer%20Package) with the correct tasks for deploying your other applications.  The only condition is that the manager app itself is deployed and running properly as ant deploy tasks depend on it.

You would need to put your .war files in a different location than your app base, and then deploy them once Tomcat is started.